# Powershell - Export CSV file correctly

Tags: powershell

I am trying to export inbox rules for users via powershell.  But , I can not get correctly export as CSV file.

```
Get-Mailbox "user@contoso.com" |Get-InboxRule | select name,Identity,ForwardTo,ForwardAsAttachmentTo, RedirectTo, DeleteMessage , Description
```

Output :

```
Name                  : [forward apply]
Identity              : contoso.local/IT/USERS/User\3315794656083574785
ForwardTo             :
ForwardAsAttachmentTo :
RedirectTo            : {"user1@gmail.com" [SMTP:user1@gmail.com]}
DeleteMessage         : False
Description           : Take the following actions:
                            redirect the message to 'user1@gmail.com'
                            and stop processing more rules on this message
```

After  I want to export it. But, I am not getting to export as correctly for attributes such as Description and RedirectTo attribute.

```
Get-Mailbox "user@contoso.com" |Get-InboxRule | select name,Identity,ForwardTo,ForwardAsAttachmentTo, RedirectTo, DeleteMessage,Description | Export-csv "C:\temp\inbox_ruleexport.csv" -NoTypeInformation -encoding UTF8
```

Output :

```
"Name","Identity","ForwardTo","ForwardAsAttachmentTo","RedirectTo","DeleteMessage","Description"
"[forward apply]","contoso.local/IT/USERS/User\3315794656083574785",,,"Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.Management.ADRecipientOrAddress[]","False","Take the following actions:
    redirect the message to 'user1@gmail.com'
    and stop processing more rules on this message
"
```

Comment: Looks like the correct output to me, or do you mean you don't want the newlines in the Description field?

Comment: yes , I want to export single line ""Take the following actions:
    redirect the message to 'user1@gmail.com'
    and stop processing more rules on this message
""

Comment: Also , I am getting ""Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.Management.ADRecipientOrAddress[]""  for Redirectto Attribute.

Comment: Normally ,  it stored value like "RedirectTo            : {"user1@gmail.com" [SMTP:user1@gmail.com]}"

Comment: If they're arrays, you might have to do an extra -join.  It's cool that a csv can have a multiline field.  Showing the result of import-csv might help with the question.

Comment: If you really want description on one line `$_.description -replace '\r\n',' '`  I don't have any redirecto properties.

Comment: Change `RedirectTo` into a calculated property 
`@{Name = 'RedirectTo'; Expression = { $_.RedirectTo -join ';'}}`. If you want to 'normalize` the description, do 
`@{Name = 'Description'; Expression = { $_.Description -replace '\s+', ' ' }}`